# How can i speed up coffee script asset compilation on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript

Ruby on Rails 3.2 with lots of small coffee script files take a huge amount of time to deploy:

Is there any way to speed up asset compilation on Heroku?

```
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promote/show/templates/_integrate.js  (271ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promote/show/templates/show_layout.js  (336ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/list_controller.js  (260ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/list_view.js  (236ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/templates/_empty.js  (335ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/templates/_promotion.js  (380ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/templates/_promotions.js  (368ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/list/templates/list_layout.js  (284ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/manage_promotions_app.js  (238ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/new_edit/new_edit_controller.js  (267ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/new_edit/new_edit_view.js  (241ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_promotions/new_edit/templates/new_edit_layout.js  (301ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_statistics/list/list_controller.js  (264ms)  (pid 7108)
   Compiled backbone/apps/manage_statistics/list/list_view.js  (231ms)  (pid 7108)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Precompile assets locally**

You can compile your assets locally, add them to source control and push them to Heroku:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "Precompile assets"
```

Heroku will then detect the precompiled assets and skip compilation

```
-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-3-asset-pipeline for additional info

**Option 2: Use memcache caching for sprockets**

Via http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/faster-deploys (DISCLAIMER: I have not tried this approach.)

Enable a memcache add-on

```
heroku addons:add memcachier
```

Add `dalli` and `memcachier` to your Gemfile.

Configure asset cache store in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Comment: that would mean assets are part of git, i'm not sure i want to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a 2nd option (Have not tried it yet)